# Deploy simple server code to Heroku

Tags: java, sockets, heroku

I recently visited heroku.com site and tried to deploy my first java program there , I actually had a good start using their java deployment tutorial, and had it run ok. now I have a server code which I need to deploy there , I tried to follow the example but I had some question in mind like,

1- what will be the host in this case , I already tried the app link as if its the host but it throws errors ,

here is my sample server code

```
public class DateServer {

    /** Runs the server. */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(6780);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println(new Date().toString());
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my client code

```
public class DateClient {

    /** Runs the client as an application. First it displays a dialog box asking for the IP address or hostname of a host running the date server, then connects to it and displays the date that it serves. */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //I used my serverAddress is my external ip address 
        Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 6780);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String answer = input.readLine();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I followed this tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java at their site to upload my server code is there something else I need to do ?!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

On Heroku, your application must [bind to the HTTP port provided in the $PORT environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#web-dynos). Given this, the two major problems in your application code above are 1) you are binding to a hardcoded port (`6780`) and 2) your application is using TCP instead of HTTP. As shown in the [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java), use something like Jetty to accomplish the HTTP equivalent of your application and use `System.getenv("PORT")` to bind to the right port, like this:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().print(new Date().toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Server server = new Server(Integer.valueOf(System.getenv("PORT")));
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(context);
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloWorld()),"/*");
        server.start();
        server.join();   
    }
}
```

Comment: ok but will be the client code a normal http connection in this case?! this actually fairly simple example, what I am really doing is building multiplayer game where clients can connect to server and play so I am interested about ur client code after ur change in the server code thanks in advance ? please remember that I am intending to extend the code to support multiplayer so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, your client would need to be using HTTP as well. Heroku applications can make outbound TCP connections (e.g. to a database), but all inbound connections need to be over HTTP. See [info about  Heroku HTTP routing](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing) for more details.