# Deploy Server Client Multiplayer to heroku

Tags: java, sockets, heroku

I have a simple Server - Client Tic Tac Toe game which run in console, I successfully run this code on my local host what I need now is to deploy the server code on server like Heroku for example , or any other hosting site other than me to be the host, I already followed Heroku tutorial but still can't figure out the rest https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java

here is my server code

```
public class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        // String clientSentence;
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6780);

        BufferedReader[] inFromClient = new BufferedReader[2];
        Socket[] connectionSocket = new Socket[2];
        DataOutputStream[] outToClient = new DataOutputStream[2];
        String labels = "XO";
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            connectionSocket[i] = welcomeSocket.accept();
            inFromClient[i] = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket[i].getInputStream()));
            outToClient[i] = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket[i].getOutputStream());
            outToClient[i].write(labels.charAt(i));
            System.out.println("one is here");
        }
        int next = 0;
        while (true) {
            String s = inFromClient[next].readLine();
            next ^= 1;
            outToClient[next].writeBytes(s + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

here is my client code

```
class TCPClient {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        String sentence;
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(server, port);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        char[][] XO = new char[3][3];
        for (char[] arr : XO)
            Arrays.fill(arr, '-');
        char playerSign = (char) inFromServer.read();
        boolean turn = false;
        if (playerSign == 'X')
            turn = true;
        while (true) {
            if (turn) {
                sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
                String[] split = sentence.split(" ");
                int a = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
                if (XO[a][b] != '-')
                    continue;
                outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
                XO[a][b] = playerSign;
                turn = false;
            } else {

                String next = inFromServer.readLine();
                String[] split = next.split(" ");
                XO[Integer.parseInt(split[0])][Integer.parseInt(split[1])] = playerSign == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
                turn = true;
            }
            for (char[] arr : XO)
                System.out.println(new String(arr));

        }
        // clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

now I already tried to put the same server code on heroku but it didn't work. I am sure I am getting something wrong,  and I am not sure about what server and port should my client connect to , any help in this matter would be appreciated

Comment: I would also appreciate if any one can tell me if there is a server even paid one , which I can upload the code directly without updating it.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574085/deploy-simple-server-code-to-heroku? The answer given there is going to apply to this question as well.

Comment: actually know the solution there won't work , as every time u connect using http connection all of the server code do is restart every thing again, which basic what suits the the pointed question as it just prints time, while now u r monitoring two clients having a game so what will u do then that;s why I modified the post to this

Comment: The server is probably crashing, perhaps at least partly due to the fact that you're not listening on the port Heroku assigns to your app (both that problem and its solution are described in the your other question).

Answer (score 1):

Heroku does not support the TCP protocol first of all, and secondly, you must bind your server to the port that the service provides you with. In node.js for example, you access this using `process.env.PORT`, however I admit my ignorance in accessing this variable via Java. But even if you did use the port they provided, only HTTP and HTTPS are supported (and websockets if you enable them through their labs), but they do not have any support for TCP.